# Callback function returning an anonymous function giving error on onClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {
  const handleClick = () => (label: string) => {
    console.log('label: ' + label)
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick('red one')}>click me</button>
}
```

TypeScript compiler is complaining on my code, what I have done wrong?

```
Type '(label: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'label' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1494, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'
```

Comment: `handleClick` doesn't take a parameter, yet you're calling it with one.

Comment: @VLAZ, the first wrapper function should be called by react with the Event argument, the inner wrapper is what should be called by me

Comment: And you use the return value of it as the actual handler, yet a handler cannot accept string, it accepts an event. As the error tells you.

Comment: "*the first wrapper function should be called by react with the Event argument, the inner wrapper is what should be called by me*" that's very much not happening. *You* are calling the first function. It doesn't magically get called and then assigned back to the same `const` variable you had at the start.

Comment: @VLAZ. OK thanks I solved the problem, it was the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around,

it should be

```
(label: string) => (e: any) => {
```

instead of

```
(e: any) => (label: string) => {
```

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {
  const handleClick = (label: string) => (e: any) => {
    console.log('label: ' + label)
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick('red one')}>click me</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `handleClick` function doesn't expect any type of parameter but you are passing it a string.

It should be:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {
  const handleClick = (label: string) => () => {
    console.log('label: ' + label)
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick('red one')}>click me</button>
}
```